# .htaccess redirect / rewrite condition with exact match

Tags: .htaccess

I need to redirect a url like this:

```
https://zzz.com/Class/Today-Class-100
```

to

```
https://zzz.com/otherfolder/
```

BUT leave a url like this

```
https://zzz.com/de/Class/Today-Class-100
```

alone. Right after the .com we have language directories, and those should not redirect. Only the first one should - how do I redirect an EXACT URL and leave ones with any difference alone?

This did not work:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/Class/Today-Class-101$ https://zzz.com/otherfolder/
```

as it still redirected with a subfolder in front of

```
/Class/Today-Class-101$
```

Comment: Your rule appears to be correct. Test it from command line `curl` or from a new browser.

Comment: I have tested, both from CL and browser and it does not work. The language sub directories - https://zzz.com/de/Class/Today-Class-100 is getting redirected

Comment: Do you have more than one .htaccess? If not provide your full .htaccess in question

Comment: Thats it, thats the rule Im using. I can't get it to ignore the language subdirectory in the redirect so only the English (no lang subdirectory) gets redirected.

Comment: `^/Class/Today-Class-101$` cannot match `/de/Class/Today-Class-100` unless there is some other .htaccess / rule / code somewhere else.

Comment: Does `/Class/Today-Class-100` map to a physical directory? Or is this just a virtual URL? And you have no other rules in this `.htaccess` file and no other `.htaccess` files? Make sure you've cleared your browser (and any intermediary) caches.

Comment: I think there is something else at play with the lang directories, as they are virtual directories. I appreciate the confirmation that ^/Class/Today-Class-101$ should work

Comment: "the lang directories, as they are virtual directories" - then you must have other directives (`.htaccess` or server config) that handle the routing of these?

Comment: Its a translation service that does dynamic translations. Not .htaccess but some stuff in smartling routes them. Is it accurate to say that this SHOULD work? RedirectMatch 301 ^/Class/Today-Class-101$ https://zzz.com/otherfolder/

Comment: Yes, that _should_ work. The pattern `^/Class/Today-Class-101$` is anchored at the beginning and end, so this matches _only_ exactly `/Class/Today-Class-101`, and nothing else. _"Not .htaccess but some stuff in smartling routes them."_ - and that's what exactly, this "smartling"?